# Extracting titles from PDFs based on formatting via classification

Tags: python, pdf, nlp

I have about 20000 pdfs with probably 100 different layouts. Unfortunately, not all PDFs contain clean metadata. People are often lazy and did not always provide the title with it or sometimes a very short one or even worse just the file name as title.

Because of the number of documents, I started with PyMuPDF before diving into deep learning (e.g layout-parser, layout_lm etc.).

A naive implementation would be to filter for the text with the largest font size at the beginning of the document. But as can be seen here that does not work well for different layouts:
[title and subtitle](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/overview/vectormune-nd-epar-summary-public_en.pdf),
[old format](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/scientific-guideline/ich-q-7-good-manufacturing-practice-active-pharmaceutical-ingredients-step-5_en.pdf),
[simple example for which a naive solution works well](https://www.ema.europa.eu/system/files/documents/scientific-guideline/wc500191492_en.pdf)

I thought about training a classifier based on a feature matrix created like:

```
def create_feature_matrix(blocks):
    """
    blocks created using pymupdf like:
    # Open the PDF file
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    # Extract data from the first page
    page = doc[0]
    text_instances = page.get_text("dict")["blocks"]
    """
    text_instances = blocks

    # Initialize the feature matrix
    feature_matrix = []

    # Iterate through text instances and extract features
    for instance in text_instances:
        if "lines" in instance:
            for line in instance["lines"]:
                for span in line["spans"]:
                    # Extract text, color, and positional information
                    text = span["text"]
                    color = span["color"]
                    size = span["size"]
                    font = span["font"]
                    bbox = span["bbox"]  # bbox = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
                    feature_matrix.append({
                        "text": text,
                        "color": color,
                        "size": size,
                        "font": font,
                        "x0": bbox[0],
                        "y0": bbox[1],
                        "x1": bbox[2],
                        "y1": bbox[3]
                    })

    return feature_matrix
```

this code could be used together with PyMuPDF like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import fitz
pdf_path = some_path
doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
# Extract data from the first page
page = doc[0]
blocks = page.get_text("dict")["blocks"]
FM_for_one_page = pd.DataFrame(create_feature_matrix(blocks))
```

My plan is to manually label the rows based on the text like: text is title: 1, not a title: 0.

This solution might be an improvement to my naive rule based classifier. However, I doubt my approach is very robust and it opens more questions:

- Would it be ok to just concatenate the feature matrices for all first pages? I do loose the information about the page boundaries. But I have no idea what else I could do.
- The features of the titles depend on the surrounding structure and sequence. What model could capture that?
- Do you think I am on a right path? If not, how would you tackle such a challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have ~100 Layouts, you are essentially re-inventing the wheel here. My gut feel based on what you've said so far is that you'd probably get more value in investing in an OCR system where you can create those ~100 Layouts/Templates with a drag and drop GUI, with workflows embedded for a user to manually review and correct any mistakes that are picked up.

Personally, I really wouldn't go down the coding route for this one if you want to keep your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdf2Data application to do this

**app**: https://standalone.pdf2data.online/

**documentation how to do it**: https://pdf2data.apryse.com/documentation/